# How to understand or show this?

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

We have

$$F=ABh^{p_1}+\theta (h^{p_2})$$
$$G=Ah^{p_1}+\theta (h^{p_2})$$

We $A$,$B$ are real numbers, $h$  positive,  $|h|\leq 1$ , $p_1<p_2$ natural numbers and $\theta(h)$ means that it is of order of $h$.
 Then we must have this:

$$\frac{F}{G}=B+\theta(h^{p_2-p_1})$$

I can´t  see the reason, can you please show me how to undestand this?

We have 
$$\frac{F}{G}=\frac{ABh^{p_1}+\theta (h^{p_2})}{Ah^{p_1}+\theta (h^{p_2})}=...$$

How to continue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to do polynomial division? This is just polynomial long division. This is a little challenging to typeset, so I'll explain.

$$
\begin{array}{r@{\,}c@{\,}lclcl}
  & & B & + & \theta(h^{p_2 - p_1}) \\
\hline
Ah^{p_1}+\theta(h^{p_2})&\big)& ABh^{p_1} &+& \theta(h^{p_2}) \\
 - & & ABh^{p_1} & + & B\theta(h^{p_2}) \\
\hline
 = & & 0 & + & \color{green}{(1-B)\theta(h^{p_2})} \\
 - & &   &   & \color{red}{Ah^{p_1}\theta(h^{p_2-p_1})} \\
\hline
 = & &   &   & \theta(h^{p_2})
\end{array}
$$

We perform long division just like normal. Multiplying $Ah^{p_1}$ by $B$ gets us $ABh^{p_1}$. Then carrying this through, we subtract off $ABh^{p_1}+B\theta(h^{p_2})$ from the divisor. Subtracting off gives us the green term. However, using $\theta$ notation, we want to recognize that $\color{green}{(1-B)\theta(h^{p_2}) \sim \theta(h^{p_2})}$.

Repeating, we find the same thing with the red term, noting that $\color{red}{Ah^{p_1}\theta(h^{p_2-p_1}) \sim \theta(h^{p_2})}$.

Subtracting two terms of the same order gives us something of the order $h^{p_2}$. But we can neglect this, since the $|h|<1$. Why? Because $p_2 > p_1$, so $h^{p_2}$ is going to shrink faster than $h^{p_2-p_1}$, and hence it gets "wrapped into" $\theta(h^{p_2-p_1})$.

Answer (score 0):

It's about the limit $h\to 0$, and it is tacitly assumed that $AB\ne0$. Put $p_2-p_1=:\rho>0$. Then
$$F(h)=AB h^{p_1}\bigl(1+O(h^\rho)\bigr), \qquad G(h)=A h^{p_1}\bigl(1+O(h^\rho)\bigr)\qquad (h\to0)\ .$$
It follows that
$${F(h)\over G(h)}=B\ {1+O(h^\rho)\over 1+O(h^\rho)}\qquad (h\to0)\ .\tag{1}$$
What does the strange expression ($=:Q(h)$) on the right side of the last equation mean? It means that there are an $h_0>0$, a constant $C>0$ and two functions $g_1(h)$, $g_2(h)$ defined for $0<h<h_0$, such that $|g_i(h)|\leq C$ $\>(0<h<h_0)$ and
$$Q(h)={1+h^\rho g_1(h)\over 1+h^\rho g_2(h)}\qquad (0<h<h_0)\ .$$
It follows that
$$\left|{Q(h)-1\over h^\rho}\right|=\left|{g_1(h)-g_2(h)\over 1+h^\rho g_2(h)}\right|\leq 4C\qquad(0<h<h_1)\ ,$$
so that we can write $$Q(h)=1+O(h^\rho)\qquad (h\to0)\ .$$
Introducing this into $(1)$ and absorbing the factor $B\ne0$ into the $O$ we obtain
$${F(h)\over G(h)}= B+\>O(h^\rho)\qquad (h\to0)\ ,$$ as stated.